# Is $\sin(x)$ =$-\sin(180^o+x)$?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, elementary-functions

I figured out that $\sin(x)$ should equal $-\sin(180+x)$ like in this picture

[image]

But when I type on Wolfram $$\sin(a\mathrm{deg})=-\sin(180+a \mathrm{deg})$$ it says it's false. Why? I've tested it using my calculator and it's right. Is this formula wrong?

Comment: The formula is correct. $-\sin(x + \pi) = \sin(x)$, in radians. What is likely happening is that wolfram is interpreting your input in radians.

Comment: Definitely true as the image shows.  Wolfram, being a bit of software that reads input, is clearly misinterpreting the input.  The most likely reason is it is not seeing "180" as "$180\deg$" but maybe as 180 radians ($57.3 \pi =116.62\deg$) which isn't true.  But once you figure out how the input is supposed to be entered it will work (if Wolram is accurate).

Answer (score 1):

We know:
sin(A+B)=sin A cos B + cos A sin B

And therefore:
sin(180 + x) = -sin (x)

And in end we have: 
sin(x) = -sin(180 + x)

Answer (score -1):

When I entered "sin(x deg) = -sin(180 deg + x deg)" into WA, I got the response "True."  Note I specified "180 deg" and not just "180 + x deg."  I also put spacing in "x deg" (not just "xdeg").  I'm not sure what WA requires, but some experimentation should provide clues.

Answer (score -1):

According to my calculations,the answer is yes. sin(45) is the same as -sin 225 (180+45)=.7071.  Hope this helps.